# How to remove an unused GIT branch in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, git, version-control, git-branch

I can see how to create a branch, but I would like to remove one that I will never use. There doesn't seem to be such functionality in Xcode, so I tried in terminal doing

```
git branch -d BugFixes
```

but no luck.

Comment: It would help to describe why `branch -d` didn't work, such as by providing any error messages that occurred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please try:

for local: git branch -D BugFixes
for remote: git push origin :BugFixes

Comment: `-D` deletes the branch even if the commits are not in any other tag or branch; i.e. it destroys on the local machine whatever work is only in that branch. (For a limited amount of time it can be recovered using the reflog). `-d`, as a safety measure, only works to delete a branch when that deletion is not destructive. `push origin :BugFixes` will then destroy the work on the remote machine (again, with a limited time way to recover using the reflog).

Answer (score 22):

You can delete git branches in Xcode. Choose Source Control > WorkingCopy > Configure WorkingCopy, where WorkingCopy is the name of your working copy, which is usually the name of your project. A sheet opens. Click the Branches button at the top of the sheet. Select a branch and click the minus button at the bottom to remove the branch. Note that Xcode does not let you remove the current branch.

[image]

**Xcode 9 Update**

Apple moved the user interface for branches to the source control navigator in Xcode 9.

[image]

To delete a branch, select it, right-click, and choose Delete. You cannot delete the current branch.

Comment: deleting the branch from `Remotes` also delete it from  `Github` ?? because in my case I get the branch back after `Fatch Changes` click ...

Comment: It should remove the remote branch from GitHub. If not, John Diaz's accepted answer to this question shows how to remove the remote branch from the Terminal.